# The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: package-repositories, gnutls

When running `package-list-packages` I get the following errors:

```
Failed to download `gnu' archive.
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

I am running Emacs 24.4 on Windows. Until this week package downloads were happening normally.

I've tried [this guide](http://xn--9dbdkw.se/diary/how_to_enable_GnuTLS_for_Emacs_24_on_Windows/index.en.html) on setting up Emacs-GnuTLS-Windows. I tried running this code from the **See if it works** section:

```
(condition-case e
    (delete-process
     (gnutls-negotiate
      :process (open-network-stream "test" nil "www.google.com" 443)
      :hostname "www.google.com"
      :verify-error t))
  (error e))
```

I do get `nil` inserted into the buffer, with no validation error, which according to the article is a sign of success. However, if I set `(setq gnutls-log-level 2)` and run the code again, I get the following output.

```
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) allocating credentials
gnutls.c: [2] (Emacs) allocating x509 credentials
gnutls.c: [2] (Emacs) using default verification flags
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) setting the trustfile:  c:/gnutls/cacert.pem
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) gnutls callbacks
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) gnutls_init
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) got non-default priority string: NORMAL
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) setting the priority string
gnutls.c: [audit] Note that the security level of the Diffie-Hellman key exchange has been lowered to 256 bits and this may allow decryption of the session data

gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) non-fatal error: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again. [1428 times]
gnutls.c: [2] (Emacs) Deallocating x509 credentials
```

So that seems a bit odd. According to [this mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2013-11/msg00120.html), the error isn't usually harmful. Nevertheless, I still cannot download `gnu`.

How can I restore normal package fetching?

#### June update

Although there are some suggestions on GitHub that the error message is spurious, `gnu` still fails to fetch. I confirmed this by checking local package versions with recently updates to the [online repository](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/).

#### 24.5 update

I can no longer reproduce the issue after upgrading to Emacs 24.5.

Comment: This just looks as if the repository was down (the server serving the packages was offline). Can you access the server by other means? (eg. via browser).

Comment: Yes. This is the repository: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/

Comment: I get the same kind of output, suggesting that this is not a sign of an error.

Comment: That is also my impression, but I thought I should post it for completeness.

Comment: I get this error too but doesn't seem to cause any harm. Package fetches work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can no longer reproduce the issue after upgrading to the the latest stable Emacs (currently 24.5). <kbd>C-h N</kbd> shows that a number of changes have been made to package signatures in that version.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug with the interaction of some versions of emacs with some versions of gnutls:

https://github.com/nicferrier/elmarmalade/issues/55#issuecomment-75377455

Comment: I can accept this answer if the relevant information is extracted from the link as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259, and if the resulting answer is sufficient to give users with the same problem a decent chance of fixing it.